# mysql-server install won't create mysql.sock file | can't connect server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp

I'm trying to connect to phpmyadmin in localhost and retrieve my db but I'm facing an issue that I can't fix. When I try to connect to mysql service I get this error :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' 
(2 "No such file or directory")
```

I supposed my file wasn't created at the right place and I've seen many relative questions on SO (I'm aware it can be a duplicate here), but I've fount no answer yet by consulting these topics..

I've tried :

- restarting mysql service (of course) -> nothing changed
- purge mysql-server and reinstall it but no sock file is created when reinstalling
- locate my sock file with `sudo find / -name mysql.sock` output is empty
- locate my sock file with `mysqladmin | grep mysql.sock` but this only look for socket conf in my my.cnf file

I know I can't create this file by myself as it's a pipe file with unusual format.

Does anyone know how to proceed here ? :D

Answer (score 1):

Either MySQL isn't running or the path to the socket is correct (as you've tried to sort out). MySQL uses two different connection types to listen with, TCP/IP networking and sockets. As a note, MySQL's privilege system differentiates between the two, so a user with the host value of `%` will not allow connections over socket, and the host `localhost` won't match a TCP/IP connection, even one that comes from the same local machine (127.0.0.1 to MySQL).

If your user account exists with both host fields, you could change the phpMyAdmin configuration to connect via the TCP/IP connection. Edit the configuration file, `config.inc.php`, and change the directive `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`

However, probably a better solution is to fix the path to your socket. I don't exactly understand what was wrong with the `mysqladmin | grep mysql.sock` command, that should have given you the path to the socket. All programs use the same socket path to connect to MySQL, so even though that's the path used by mysqladmin and the other command line tools, it's also the path you'll use for phpMyAdmin. Another way to get it is by connecting through the command-line client and running the `STATUS;` command. There will be a line like this: `UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

Either way, once you have the path, you can add it directly to `config.inc.php` by adding (or editing, if it already exists) the socket directive: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';`.

A slightly better approach would be edit your PHP configuration and set it globally so all PHP programs know the correct path. In your `php.ini`, the correct directive should be `mysqli.default_socket`. PHP takes the "built-in MySQL defaults" unless you override it here, and phpMyAdmin takes the PHP setting unless you override it in config.inc.php. So any of those solutions will solve the problem for you. The easiest is probably setting it for phpMyAdmin only, but if you're doing other PHP development it may simplify things to define it globally in php.ini.

Comment: Thanks Isaac but `mysqladmin | grep mysql.sock` had no output in my case, I guess I just had no socket file at all... Anyway, it resolved by itself when I re-ran apt-get install mysql-server after restarting my service. I d'ont know what happened here, it's confusing but it's fixed yet :)